# junit not cleaning up logger after test execution

Tags: java, junit, log4j, resource-cleanup

I am creating some junit tests for some legacy code. In those classes there are many calls to a logger that is a custom subclass of java.util.logging.Logger . For every call the class that handles the logger checks whether the logger is initialized retrieving it by name with a java.util.logging.LogManager.
The problem I have is that if I run two test cases in a row I get a class cast exception. I investigated for a while and I found out that when the second test runs the LogManager finds an existing instance of a Logger, but if I call `logger instanceof MyLogging.class` on that logger I get a `false`, if I call `logger.getClass()` I get `MyLogging.class`

My assumption is that junit didn't clean up all the resources between the two tests. An instance of the logger remained in memory, but somehow it was cast to the superclass.

I tried to create a tearDown method annotated with `@After`, In the method I called `LogManager.reset()`. It didn't work, the javadoc says that this method removes all the handlers, but it doesn't mention the logger, so it seems it is not the functionality I needed. I searched all over the documentation to find out a way to remove a logger, but I couldn't find anything.

I don't know whether it is related, but 2 out of 5 test classes are annotated with: `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`

Any idea on how to clean up properly the resources or remove the logger is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to investigate and clarify something... this statement is impossible in Java. `logger instanceof MyLogging.class on that logger I get a false, if I call logger.getClass() I get MyLogging.class`

Comment: It seems strange, but it is exactly what happens. I even tried to print canonical and simple name within brackets to check for spaces or any other strange character, but the name was all right. The exception message  is something like: MyLogging.class cannot be cast to MyLogging.class